# Can I transfer catagorised symbol groupings to to an attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I have a layer file in ArcGIS 10.2 that symbolizes some points by category. 100s of different values in the value field have been grouped down to about 20 symbols. Unfortunately the data I want is these symbols. I can see this but I want to be able to read it as an attribute or select all points that share a symbol?

Is there anyway I can export the symbol definition to a table or select according to symbol?

Comment: Are your values text or numeric?  How are these values grouped?  Are they distinct values grouped together, or a range of values?  e.g. 1,5,8 in one group, 15, 22, 67 in another group or in ranges like 0-20, 21-40 etc.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from the inclusion of a picture showing the Symbology tab of your Layer Properties.